# I am comparing two JavaScript objects using jsonpatch.compare method and making a patch call

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, json-patch

If one property value of both objects is same it setting to null or empty, but I don't want to set anything if both property values are same. How do I do that?

```
obj1 = { name: 'red', age: 12 }
obj2 = { name: 'yellow' age: 12 }

jsonPatch.compare(obj1, obj2);
```

> Output:
>
> { op: "replace", path: "/Name", value: "yellow"},
>
> { op: "replace", path: "/age", value: ""},

I don't want to update age if it is same